# Weight decay used by Adam optimizer for neural network caused NaN validation loss

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, regularization

I've built a model with BCE loss for CTR prediction in which the major part is a transformer encoder. I've used 0.1 for dropout probability. When using 0 weight decay for Adam the training and validation losses both decreased normally. However **when using 1e-4 or 1e-6 as the weight decay, after some steps, the validation loss became NaN**. What is the possible reason for it? The training loss never became NaN though.
[image]
[image]

What does NaN validation loss indicate? Does it mean -log(0)?